# Getting my "beer" vertical progress bar to work

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

I'm trying to make a progress bar that looks like emptying glass of beer. Unfortunately I'm not very artistic person but I'm doing my best.

My concept goes like this:

1. There is a `<div>` with "beer" background, 100% high vertically. It hides any overflow
2. Inside there's another `<div>`, positioned relatively to the parent. It contains:

   1. White background `<div>` to obscure "beer" pattern when it's gone
   2. The image of beer foam cap

Here's the concept on picture:

[image]

I almost succeeded in my goal, as you can see in this snippet:

<sub>**Note:** the animation requires ES6 async/await</sub>

```js
Promise.timeout = function (delay) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(resolve, delay);
            });
        };
        Promise.animationFrame = function () {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                requestAnimationFrame(resolve);
            });
        };
        (async function () {
            const progress = document.querySelector("div.top");
            for (let i = 0, l = 1000; i < l; ++i) {
                progress.style.bottom = (100 - i / 10) + "%";
                await Promise.animationFrame();
            }
        })();
```

```css
html, body, div {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.progress {
    max-width:300px;
    width: 100vw;
    
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/SKfSqEv.jpg");
    background-size: 500px;

    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
div.progress div.top {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 100%;
}
div.progress div.top div.white{
    background-color: white;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
div.progress div.top div.beer-top {
    /*background-image is at the bottom since it is bse64 */
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position-y: bottom;
    background-position-x: left;
    background-size: 302px, 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
/*div.progress div.top {
    background-position: bottom;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("img/beer-top.png");
}*/
div.main {
    float: left;
}

div.progress div.top div.beer-top {
    background-image:  url('https://preview.ibb.co/k2x2V6/beer_top.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
        <div class="top">
            <div class="white"></div>
        <div class="beer-top"></div>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="progress-area">


        </div>-->
    </div>

    <div class="main">

    </div>
```

But there are two big issues:

1. This ugly orange line:
    [image]
2. Because I set `div.white` height to `100%`, the foam is pushed down and is visible even at "100%" state. It also disappears completely at the end. The desired state is this:
    [image]

How to fix those two issues?

I'm looking for CSS only solution, so that the bar can be displayed statically as well (eg. at 40% when the page loads without javascript).

Also note: setting the foam as background for the "white div" is not an option, because the bottom of the foam image is transparent.

Comment: how to fix? drink more beer and you won't even notice it!

Comment: I'm not seeing the orange line that you're talking about. I'm on Chrome - what browser are you using?

Comment: @AlexvonBrandenfels I see it in both chrome and firefox. But it might depend on screen properties. I assume it happens because there's a tiny gap between "white" div and "foam" div.

Comment: I think your orange line is from the beer behind the foam

Comment: @MattThurston exactly, as I said in the comment above. I fixed it by adding `margin-top: -2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there was a need for a CSS only solution. You could add the foam to your 'white' div as a background and a white gradient (ofcourse some tweeking is needed with the image to show up perfectly).

See JSfiddle:

```js
            Promise.timeout = function (delay) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(resolve, delay);
            });
        };
        Promise.animationFrame = function () {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                requestAnimationFrame(resolve);
            });
        };
        (async function () {
            const progress = document.querySelector("div.top");
            for (let i = 0, l = 1000; i < l; ++i) {
                progress.style.bottom = (100 - i / 10) + "%";
                await Promise.animationFrame();
            }
        })();
```

```css
html, body, div {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.progress {
    max-width:300px;
    width: 100vw;
    
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/SKfSqEv.jpg");
    background-size: 500px;

    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
div.progress div.top {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 100%;
}
div.progress div.top div.white{
    background-color: white;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
div.progress div.top div.beer-top {
    /*background-image is at the bottom since it is bse64 */
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position-y: bottom;
    background-position-x: left;
    background-size: 302px, 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
/*div.progress div.top {
    background-position: bottom;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("img/beer-top.png");
}*/
div.main {
    float: left;
}

div.progress div.top div.beer-top {
    background-image:  url('https://preview.ibb.co/k2x2V6/beer_top.png');
}

.top {
    background: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-image:  url('https://preview.ibb.co/k2x2V6/beer_top.png'),linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 1%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 5%);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
        <div class="top">
        </div>
        <!--<div class="progress-area">


        </div>-->
    </div>

    <div class="main">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So the fixes I figured out were:

1. Add `margin-top: -1` to `div.beer-top` to erase the orange line. The white and foam divs now overlap, so the div under then doesn't shine through.
2. Use `display: flex` to make the `div.white` fill all space except the `div.beer-top`s space.

   ```
     div.progress div.top {
         height: 100%;
         position: relative;
         bottom: 100%;
         /**Modern flexbox layout*/
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column;
     }
     div.progress div.top div.white{
         background-color: white;
         width:100%;
         /*fill remaining space*/
         flex-grow: 1;
     }
   ```

```js
Promise.timeout = function (delay) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(resolve, delay);
            });
        };
        Promise.animationFrame = function () {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                requestAnimationFrame(resolve);
            });
        };
        (async function () {
            const progress = document.querySelector("div.top");
            for (let i = 0, l = 1000; i < l; ++i) {
                progress.style.bottom = (100 - i / 10) + "%";
                await Promise.animationFrame();
            }
        })();
```

```css
html, body, div {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.progress {
    max-width:300px;
    width: 100vw;
    
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/SKfSqEv.jpg");
    background-size: 500px;

    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
div.progress div.top {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 100%;
    /**Modern flexbox layout*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
div.progress div.top div.white{
    background-color: white;
    width:100%;
    /*fill remaining space*/
    flex-grow: 1;
}
div.progress div.top div.beer-top {
    /*background-image is at the bottom since it is bse64 */
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position-y: bottom;
    background-position-x: left;
    background-size: 302px, 100px;
    height: 100px;
    
    /** this should hide the blinking orange line atop*/
    margin-top:-2px;
}
/*div.progress div.top {
    background-position: bottom;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("img/beer-top.png");
}*/
div.main {
    float: left;
}

div.progress div.top div.beer-top {
    background-image:  url('https://preview.ibb.co/k2x2V6/beer_top.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
        <div class="top">
            <div class="white"></div>
        <div class="beer-top"></div>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="progress-area">


        </div>-->
    </div>

    <div class="main">

    </div>
```